# Automation testing with gauge and taiko while executing parallely many specs getting failed

Tags: linux, automated-tests, headless-browser, gauge, taiko

My automation script has 43 specs totally, when I run this specs Individually in linux headless mode, specs are getting passed. If I run all the specs parallely only few is getting passed and a lot of specs are getting failed.

Note : for each spec execution time is around 15 mins.

Kindly help to resolve this.

I have optimised the code still specs are getting failed while running parallely.

I want all the specs to pass while running parallely.

Comment: Because your specs are now running simultaneously, if your specs use *any* shared resources they could be interfering with each other. The most common examples are databases and files. Each spec needs to use its own database and its own temp files or temp directory. For example, if you have two specs which both change `output.txt` they may be clobbering each other's changes. They should instead create a temp file and test with that. Without more information, we can't help.